# Bind a CheckedlistBox to DataSource c#

Tags: c#

I want to set my data from my database into the CheckedListBox but with my code I only get error messages that say DataBinding only accepts List or ListSource.
Also with debugging mode I don't even get an error message the CheckedListBox just stays empty.

```
DataClasses1DataContext d = new DataClasses1DataContext();
////

var query = from pers in d.Person select pers;

BindingList<Person> personen = new BindingList<Person> { new Person { Name = "Name"} };

clVorfahr.DataSource = personen;
clVorfahr.DisplayMember = "Name";
clVorfahr.ValueMember = "Name";

clVorfahr.Refresh();
```

Comment: Are you sure your code is correct? clVorfahr.DataSource = Name; , i think datasource should be personen list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the wrong data source.  It should be personen not Name.

```
clVorfahr.DataSource = personen;
clVorfahr.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Comment: Oh okay. But still, when i do this that way i am only getting one entry and its called "WindwosForms.Person" and not the Datalist + i still get a error message that the DisplayMember cant be bind

Comment: Did you need to leave the displaymember and value member as strings?  I have updated example.

Comment: Also you probably need to populate personen with data.  At the moment it just looks like it will always contain one row and is not connected to your query.

Comment: haha. forget to populate the list, thx. 
if i fail i'll ask you again :D!

Comment: No worries glad to be of help.